# In Apache NiFi, how do I print current date in ISO format with timezone

Tags: apache-nifi, datetime-format, date

I am using the now() function to add a dynamic attribute to the flow. The value that's assigned to the attribute is human-readable format. I would like to get the value in the ISO format:

```
2019-09-21T12:00:00Z
```

I have tried this expression:

```
${now():format("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'")}
```

However, I am getting an error on 'T'.

```
 ERROR: failed to process session due to Illegal pattern character 'T';
```

Is there a quick way to format the date using the EL?

I am NiFi version 1.9.1

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/expression-language-guide.html#format),

```
${now():format("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'", "GMT")}
```

will give your expected result.